# MySQL split date range by month into rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a employee list with start date and end date. Everytime they change manager, a new line is generated. I am trying to figure out what was their department for each month throughout the whole year.

Here's the data:

```
EMP_ID  startdate   enddate     staffgroup
494694  2012-05-24  2013-01-09  Service
494694  2013-01-09  2013-02-03  Service
494694  2013-02-03  2013-02-04  Service
494694  2013-02-04  2013-02-05  Service
494694  2013-02-05  2013-02-07  Service
494694  2013-02-07  2013-02-15  Service
494694  2013-02-15  2013-03-20  Service
494694  2013-03-20  2013-06-01  Service
494694  2013-06-01  2013-06-03  Manager
494694  2013-06-03  2013-07-01  Manager
494694  2013-07-01  2099-12-31  Manager
```

Expected results

```
EMP_ID  Month       staffgroup
494694  2013-01-01  Service
494694  2013-02-01  Service
494694  2013-03-01  Service
494694  2013-04-01  Service
494694  2013-05-01  Service
494694  2013-06-01  Manager
494694  2013-07-01  Manager
```

Comment: Are you looking for GROUP BY MONTH(startdate)?

Comment: No, I am looking to extract the month from the range. For example, the first line the date range is 2012-05-24 to 2013-01-09.
I want to extract every month out of that range.

Comment: Then why does your desired result not contain any rows for year 2012?

Comment: It was an sample of the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DATE_HELPER table containing all the months you want:

```
the_date
2013-01-01
2013-02-01
...
2013-12-01
```

Then it looks like you want the last staffgroup that the person had before the start of each month.

```
         SELECT e.EMP_ID, max(e.startdate), dh.the_date
           FROM DATE_HELPER dh
LEFT OUTER JOIN RAW_EMP_DATA e on (e.startdate <= dh.the_date)
       GROUP BY EMP_ID, dh.the_date

Results:
EMP_ID  startdate   the_date
494694  2012-05-24  2013-01-01
494694  2013-01-09  2013-02-01
494694  2013-02-15  2013-03-01
494694  2013-03-20  2013-04-01
494694  2013-03-20  2013-05-01
494694  2013-06-01  2013-06-01
494694  2013-07-01  2013-07-01
494694  2013-07-01  2013-08-01
494694  2013-07-01  2013-09-01
494694  2013-07-01  2013-10-01
```

That gives you all of the relevant startdates you care about. So you join back to the original table to get the staffgroup:

```
    SELECT red.EMP_ID, X.the_date as Month, red.staffgroup
      FROM RAW_EMP_DATA red
INNER JOIN (
         SELECT e.EMP_ID, max(e.startdate), dh.the_date
           FROM DATE_HELPER dh
LEFT OUTER JOIN RAW_EMP_DATA e on (e.startdate <= dh.the_date)
       GROUP BY EMP_ID, dh.the_date
           ) X on (X.EMP_ID = red.EMP_ID and X.startdate = red.startdate)

Results:
EMP_ID  Month       staffgroup
494694  2013-01-01  Service
494694  2013-02-01  Service
494694  2013-03-01  Service
494694  2013-04-01  Service
494694  2013-05-01  Service
494694  2013-06-01  Manager
494694  2013-07-01  Manager
494694  2013-08-01  Manager
494694  2013-09-01  Manager
494694  2013-10-01  Manager
```

Comment: Very nice. That's the exact solution I found on google after a day of research. I did pretty much the same like you said in your post. I built a table with the 2013 calendar. I wish you answered 2 weeks ago.

Comment: I'm glad that it, er, would have helped. Maybe next time you'll get help in time to actually help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM startdate ) 

FROM  `employee`
```

will give you '201310' for october 2013

Comment: But then how do I get the dates between the range?